# Pandas: Split DataFrame into two DataFrames with equal distribution of ids with unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a DataFrame like the following:

```
userId | preference 
-------------------
   1   |  tea
   1   | coffee 
   2   | apple
   2   | apple
   2   | apple
   3   | tea
   3   | coffee
   3   | cookie
   4   | banana 
   4   | cake
```

I need to split the data frame into two Data Frames that have an equal distribution of userIds but with unique preferences. For example, userId `1` can go into both DataFrames since the user has at least two unique preferences. However, userId `2` will be ignored since there is only one unique preference.

In summary, from the original DF, I want to generate two DataFrame that will look like this:

```
DataFrame1

userId | preference 
-----------------
   1   | tea
   3   | tea
   3   | coffee
   4   | banana 
  

 DataFrame 2
 
userId | preference 
-----------------
   1   | coffee
   3   | cookie
   4   | cake
```

In other words,

```
DataFrame1['userId'].unique() == DataFrame2['userId'].unique()
```

Note: DataFrame2 gets the "leftover" rows that DataFrame1 didn't take.

I was able to filter the data just for users that have two or more unique preferences by using

```
df.groupby('userId').filter(lambda x: x['preference'].nunique()>1)
```

But stuck on getting the DataFrame to split with equal userIds for both DF

Comment: Why do two userId 3 end up in DF1?

Comment: because in the original DF, there are 3 unique preferences for userid 3. The last unique preference will go to DF2. The first two will go into DF1

Comment: Is this true no matter how many duplicates? The last always goes to the second?

Comment: yes, you can assume this

Comment: I think a more general solution would be able to select the last x rows to go over to DF2

Answer (score 1):

We can take the filtered_df and use a `dict` comprehension based on [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and keep the last `n` by comparing total [`transform count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) minus the [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and taking only rows that are less than or equal to the threshold:

```
filtered_df = (
    df.groupby('userId').filter(lambda x: x['preference'].nunique() > 1)
)

n = 1  # Keep Last 1
g = filtered_df.groupby('userId')
dfs = {
    f'df_{1 if not k else 2}': v
    for k, v in filtered_df.groupby(
        (g['userId'].transform('count') - g.cumcount()) <= n
    )
}
```

`dfs`:

```
{'df_1':    userId preference
0       1        tea
5       3        tea
6       3     coffee
8       4     banana,
 'df_2':    userId preference
1       1     coffee
7       3     cookie
9       4       cake}
```